# Questions about 4 part chord

Tags: chord-theory

Is this correct for a C major chord[image]

I am kind of confused.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's a standard stave, with G clef and F clef, then yes, because there are the three notes constituting C major - C, E and G. Order doesn't necessarily matter, that just changes the voicing, and how it's described - root, 1st, 2nd inversion. What are you actually confused about?

It must also be assumed that the line is in the key of G, making this C chord correct as the IV.

Comment: I agree the four notes C, G, E, C make a C chord.